# Spring Cloud DataFlow and originalContentType

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm using Spring Cloud Edgware and Spring Cloud DataFlow 1.2.3.

I'm having problems with contentType and originalContentType and, although I have a workaround, I'm not understanding why it's needed.

I have various dataflow streams all sinking data to a rabbit sink, 1.3.1.RELEASE of spring-cloud-starter-stream-sink-rabbit (call it datasink for the purposes of this explanation). Rabbit source in play is 1.3.1.RELEASE of spring-cloud-starter-stream-source-rabbit.

The data in the rabbit sink is correctly application/json. The streams producing the data have Processors which munge stuff and explicitly set the output contentType to application/json in the code. This has all been working correctly for over a year and still does.

There is now a need to introduce a bridge between the datasink and another rabbit sink. The new bridge stream is simply:

rabbit-source | rabbit-sink

where rabbit-source reads from the aforementioned datasink.

The sinked data in the bridge stubbornly has a contentType of application/octet-stream.

I have tried the following setting:

app.rabbit-source.spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.content-type=application/json

This results in a sinked contentType of application/json but the payload is base64 encoded! Why is base64 encoding happening?

My workaround is to hack the rabbit sink and to programmatically overwrite the contentType header with the originalContentType header if present. I don't like this at all and would welcome a better solution and more understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry you're having an issue. Content-type negotiations have improved dramatically in the later versions of spring-cloud-stream and have been completely revamped in the 2.0 branch.
So, before going any further I would recommend upgrading to the latest GA version of spring-cloud-stream which is `Ditmars.SR3` and see if that alone will address your issue, or even better to the latest 2.0 snapshot (we are very close to RC, so it is pretty stable).

Comment: Ditmars.SR3 made no difference. Using the latest 2.0 snapshot and indeed the 2.0 release when it happens are out of the question for the time being. Far too risky. My hacked rabbit sink overwriting contentType with originalContentType will have to do :(

Comment: @bikerlad Could you please try one other thing. There was a bug reported recently which was fixed and made it to SR3 and could potentially solve your issue. Basically set this application property to define `contentType` on the actual binder channel `--spring.cloud.stream.default.contentType=application/json` and let me know.

Comment: Also, if you do get a chance, please try it with 2.0 (even though I do understand you can't use it now) and if it (or above suggested solution) doesn't work please file an issue here https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues.
Thank you

Comment: I tried --spring.cloud.stream.default.contentType=application/json on the rabbit-sink component (with and without using Ditmars.SR3 everywhere). No difference to behaviour i.e. application/json is set as the contentType but the payload is still base64 encoded. I'll raise a bug on Monday as I have better things to do on a Saturday lol I'll also report back here on using 2.0 when I get a chance at some point next week. Also worth pointing out that when using named destinations i.e. > :some-queue, the contentType is always application/octet-stream with originalContentType as you'd expect. Odd.

Comment: I also tried --spring.cloud.stream.default.contentType=application/json on the rabbit-source component too, to no avail.